# JAR file execution: cannot find/load main class

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I have developed a maven project on eclipse and runs fine on it. I want to build a jar out of it and run it from command prompt. I don't want to have a big jar with all the dependencies in it. I want to have a small jar with the project code that uses 'lib' folder for dependencies (with jar files) and 'resources' folder for properties file.

plugins I have used in Maven:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>${jdk.version}</source>
            <target>${jdk.version}</target>
        </configuration>

    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathLayoutType>custom</classpathLayoutType>
                    <customClasspathLayout>lib/${artifact.artifactId}${artifact.dashClassifier?}-${artifact.version}.${artifact.extension}</customClasspathLayout>
                    <mainClass>mypkg.Main</mainClass>
                </manifest>
                <manifestEntries>
                    <Class-Path>. ${project.build.directory}\resources ${project.build.directory}\lib</Class-Path>
                </manifestEntries>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}\lib</outputDirectory>
                    <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                    <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                    <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-resources</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}\resources</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

My Main class:

```
package mypkg;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

 .......
 .......
}
}
```

The jar is getting created with a manifest file in 'META-INF' folder.
Manifest file (removed some jar entries in classpath for viewing purpose):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: userName
Class-Path: . D:/project2/mypkg/target/ D:/project2/mypkg/target/resources D:/project2/mypkg/target/lib lib/hive-jdbc.jar lib/hive-common.jar lib/commons-lang.jar 
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_101
Main-Class: mypkg.Main
```

folder structure:

```
folder-
       -lib
            -(all the jar files)
       -resources
            -(properties file)
       -application.jar
```

I am using 'java -jar application.jar mypkg.Main' from command prompt.

but it shows 'Error: Could not find or load main class mypkg.Main'

Can someone please tell me what is causing the error and how to resolve it?

Comment: Why are you adding "mypgk.Main" at the end of your command?

Comment: Just to be sure. Even if i don't it shows the same error.

Comment: If you remove the `<Class-Path>` config inside `<manifestEntries>`, does it find the main class and complain about libraries classes not present?

Comment: No. It still shows cannot find or load Main class. I ran 'java -jar application.jar'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution. Just need to do some modifications in the manifest file. The versions of the jars were missing.

Final Manifest file(removed some jar entries in classpath for viewing purpose)::

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: userName
Class-Path: lib/hive-jdbc-1.1.0.jar lib/hive-common-1.1.0.jar 
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_101
Main-Class: mypkg.Main
```

Just a note: Wild cards for example "lib/*" did not work in the 'Class-Path' header in the Manifest file (Java 6 and above).